# Add popup/reminder when user creates a new Stream

Tags: rtc

To create a new stream in RTC source control I right click on a snapshot and select 'New' -> 'Stream from Snapshot'. Is it possible to add a reminder/popup at this point to indicate to the user that certain files should be changed as part of creation of this new stream ? Or better yet update the files on the stream itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to add a popup on the Stream creation.

You could define a hook, but the "Team Configuration / Operation Behavior" section doesn't include a "Create Stream" action.
So there don't seem to be any *native* way to achieve what you need.

Comment: thanks, I could possibly do this using the scm tool ? Is this possible using the scm tool : create a stream from a snapshot, create a repository workspace and check out all components into that repository workspace and add them to the Eclipse workspace, then just update the files via my custom script ?

Comment: @user470184 yes, a script would work. The difference being you would need to deploy that script, as opposed to register it centrally as a hook for all user to execute it automatically.